# C language: implementing a if-then-else-if structure using a nested if-then-if structure

Tags: c, nested

i want to implement this if-then-else-if structure :

```
if ( a > b )
    a = a - 1;
else if ( b >= c )
    b = b − 2;
else if ( c > d)
    c = c + d;
else
    d = d / 2;
```

using a nested if-then-if structure. I tried this code but it didn't give me the same results as the first code:

```
if ( c > d)
    if ( b >= c)
        if ( a > b)
            a=a-1;
        else
            b=b-2;
    else
        c=c+d;
else
    d=d/2;
```

Comment: Why do you want a nested structure?

Comment: `else if` is already nesting

Comment: make C drink alcohol

Comment: why? You write code for the logic you need,, and however it looks is how it looks. Deciding what the structure should be and making the logic fit that is backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
`if (a) if (b)`
```

is equivalent to

```
`if (a && b)`
```

In your case

```
if ( c > d)
  if ( b >= c)
    if ( a > b)
```

would be

```
if ( c > d && b >= c && a > b)
```

which is completely different compared to your initial code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a nesting like that, you could try

```
if (a <= b) {
    if (b < c) {
        if (c <= d) {
            d = d / 2;
        } else {
            c = c + d;
        }
    } else {
        b = b - 2;
    }
} else {
    a = a - 1;
}
```

But `else if` is much easier to read.

Comment: i tried your proposition but it did not achieve the same results like the first code of if-then-else-if structure.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the first if-condition (wrote >= instead of <=). Works for me now.